# Error Code -193 on db2

Tags: database, db2

I want to alter some table on my database, this is a sql and error message. i have searched on db2 documentation and google, but I did not find it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you see a SQLCODE error message such as -193,  it's the same as error message SQL0193.  The easiest way to get help is to use a db2 command window and type

```
db2 ? SQL193
```

The message indicates that you can't add a not null column without a default.  Include a default when you add the column, and then if you don't want a default value, then drop the default with a second alter table statement.

```
SQL0193N
In an ALTER TABLE statement, the column column-name has been specified as NOT NULL and    either the DEFAULT clause was not specified or was specified as DEFAULT NULL.

Explanation
When new columns are added to a table that already exists, a value must be assigned to that new column for all existing rows. By default, the null value is assigned. However, since the column has been defined as NOT NULL, a default value other than null must be defined.

User response
Either remove the NOT NULL restriction on the column or provide a default value other than null for the column.

sqlcode: -193

sqlstate: 42601

Parent topic: SQL Messages
```

Message topic

Answer (score 0):

The message marked as the answer is correct!

Here is an example for those looking for specific statements (like I was):

```
alter table table_example add SAMPLE_ID int not null default 0;
alter table table_example alter column SAMPLE_ID drop default;
```